# How can i aappend input and label in div

Tags: jquery

I have a `form`. How can I append `input` and `label` elements in that `div`?

```
<form id="registration" action="" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
    <label for="id_email">Email:</label>
    <input id="id_email" class="formControl" type="text" name="email" maxlength="60">

    <label for="id_phone_number">Phone number:</label>
    <input id="id_phone_number" class="formControl" type="text" name="phone_number" maxlength="10">

    <label for="id_zip_code">Zip Code:</label>
    <input id="id_zip_code" class="formControl" type="text" name="zip_code" maxlength="5">

    <label for="id_first_name">Name:</label>
    <input id="id_first_name" class="formControl" type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="255">

    <label for="id_last_name">Surname:</label>
    <input id="id_last_name" class="formControl" type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="255">

    <label for="id_password_reg">Password:</label>
    <input id="id_password_reg" class="formControl" type="password" name="password">

    <label for="id_confirmpassword">Confirm Password:</label>
    <input id="id_confirmpassword" class="formControl" type="password" name="confirmpassword">

    <input class="btn btnPrime btnBlock" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: i dont see any div inside

Comment: show what you have tried so far

Comment: Is the `form` wrapped in the `div`?

Comment: This form is generated form back end.I am trying to append input an label in div like this
<div>

    <label for="id_password_reg">Password:</label>
    <input id="id_password_reg" class="formControl" type="password" name="password">
</div>

Comment: @Sipan See my second answer with `wrapAll`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div").append("<label></label>");
$("div").append("<input/>");
```

This will do the trick.
This will append a `label` and an `input` to all `div`'s on the page though. Use an `id` or `class` as a selector for a more precise result

Answer (score 0):

To wrap a combination of `label` and `input` in an `div` with your example html you can use `wrapAll`:

```
$(function() {
    $("form#registration label").each(function() {
       $(this).add($(this).next()).wrapAll("<div></div>");

       // or select the input by ID instead of '.next()'
       // var input = $("input#" + $(this).attr("for"));
       // $(this).add(input).wrapAll("<div></div>");
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5x7jrvmx/